# Is there a way to modify the "Save copy of sent message" checkbox to not save a sent item?

Tags: vba, outlook

In the composition window, the Options tab has a "More Options" group. One of the options is "Save copy of sent message." This is a checkbox. If you uncheck it, Outlook does not save a copy.

That's a fair number of mouse clicks, so I was thinking of writing a VBA macro to uncheck that box in one click, but I don't see a MailItem property that affects that option.

I saw the MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder property, but it is a folder, not a boolean. I tried setting it to Nothing, but that caused Outlook to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit` property.

See all MailItem properties and methods at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem

You can see live property values of the various Outlook objects using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click the Item button.